# How to match exact user input

Tags: python

I have below code in test.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys,re

def disfun():
        a = str(raw_input('Enter your choice [PRIMARY|SECONDARY]: ')).upper().strip()
        p = re.compile(r'\s.+a+.\s')
        result = p.findall("+a+")
        print result
disfun()
```

When I run this code, it gives a prompt for Enter your choice and if I give my choice as PRIMARY. I am getting only blank output:

`[oracle@localhost oracle]$ ./test.py
Enter your choice [PRIMARY|SECONDARY]: PRIMARY
[]`

Here I want to get the same output as I given in user input. Please help me on this.

Comment: why not just `print a` what is the need behind all this

Comment: @Vignesh Kalai actually the result which I will get I need to pass in one command which runs on different server and match this result in a file.

Comment: You need to be more clear nothing is making sense now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your goal is but I think you mean this?? Mind the quotes, 'a' is your user input. If you write "+a+" it will be literaly the string '+a+'

```
def disfun():
        a = str(raw_input('Enter your choice [PRIMARY|SECONDARY]: ')).upper().strip()
        p = re.compile(r'.*'+a+'.*') <-- this will match anything containing your user input
        result = p.findall(a)
        print result
```

Comment: Thanks. with your code I am getting the outpu as:
`['SECONDARY']`
But I want only SECONDARY  not even [' or ']. Please let me know there is any possibility

Comment: I have converted the 'list' into 'string' and got my intended result. Thanks for your help